# Unwanted Line Drawn Between Ends of Curves in 3D

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

Okay, this was about one of the technical pitfalls and how to avoid it, which was solved quite easily by adding `samples y=0` as recommended by Francis.

**Initial Question**

The following does two turns of a helix and then joins the start and finish with a straight line for some reason. Plus there's some nasty overlapping happening in the smoothing process.

**MWE**

[image: MWE Output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
%
\par\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{axis}[
    scale=3,
    x={(-0.6cm,-0.3cm)}, y={(.6cm,0.0cm)}, z={(0cm,.2cm)},
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    xtick={-1,1}, ytick={-1,1},ztick={4,8},
    enlargelimits=true
    ]
\addplot3[smooth, thick, color=green, domain=0:720] ({2*sin(x)},{2*cos(x)},{2*x/180});
%
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Geoff, it would be very helpful if you would revert the edit and would generate new questions for the follow-ups. Otherwise it is really hard to keep track of what is the question and what is the answer - and it would make it impossible to accept answers even though they were complete and self-contained some time ago.

Comment: Okay, good advice, I've done as you suggest. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
samples y=0
```

to the plot option, it will get rid of the mesh line.

e.g.

```
\addplot3[smooth, thick, color=green, domain=0:720, samples y=0] ({2*sin(x)},{2*cos(x)},{2*x/180});
```

Alternatively, you can also use

```
y domain=0:0
```

Refer to page 112 of the `pgfplots` manual for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

a solution with PSTricks. Run it with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}   
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(5.5,6.5)
\psset{lightsrc=10 -20 50,viewpoint=50 -20 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\psSolid[object=grille,base=-4 4 -4 4,linecolor=red,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth]%
\axesIIID(0,0,0)(4,4,6)
\defFunction[algebraic]{helice}(t){2*sin(t)}{2*cos(t)}{t/15}
\psSolid[object=courbe,r=0,range=0 20 Pi mul,linecolor=blue,
         linewidth=0.1,resolution=360,function=helice]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I need to find time to think about this as I haven't looked at pstricks before. A whole new package to learn! Cheers